# Format a HTML document into multiple A4 size sections

Tags: html, css, printing

This is my current problem.

I want to generate a HTML page, which contains about 40 coupons. Each coupon must be with one A4 sized section.

So, if I were to print the HTML document, I would like each printed page to contain 1 coupon.

Ideas on how I could accomplish this ?

Comment: Did you try using divs with class *a4* with css `div.a4 { width:210mm; height:297mm; }`?

Comment: the size helped for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following CSS should achieve what you need, subistitute the class name for whatever is appropriate for your DOM structure

```
 @media print {
  .coupon-class 
  {
   page-break-after:always;
  }
 }
```

This will always insert a page break after the element you can also use `page-break-before` to achieve a page break before an element.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed for the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You'll never get a very precise solution using HTML, as every browser decides its way of printing HTML is best and adds all sorts of headers and footers that change the page dimensions and how the clients printer actually prints it.

You would be better off generating a PDF of your coupons which you can easily do with PHP extensions.

Comment: This is incorrect, CSS2+ has included page-break-before/after properties that are quite well supported, combined with a print media query you can actually achieve fairly dependable print styling, the only bit you cant garuntee is the users print margins, but if all you need is a garuntee of page breaks then it is easily achievable through CSS.

Comment: I don't know about now, but the last time I tried using `page-break-after:always`, it didn't work at all in Chrome and Safari. My experience with the print media query is to use it just for stripping out styling.

Comment: I agree, I would have to go with PDF as a solution as my development increases

Answer (score 0):

You can do the steps below:

1. Define the `width:100` for each coupon in its css styles. This will use maximum width of your paper.
2. Use `page-break-after:always` in css properties of each coupon. This will force the next coupon to be shown in the next page. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530842(v=vs.85).aspx)

Don't forget to be careful about your coupons height. Try to avoid putting lots of rows in them.
You can use `<fieldset>` tag for each coupon and apply css properties on it.

Comment: Did you mean `width: 100%;`?